# Computer hangs while setting up linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dpkg, virtualization

I think this system was shutdown during a system update but not sure. It doesn't say I have any available updates when I log in, so I don't know. This is a VM on a hyper-v host.

I used to face this issue while running `apt-get update`. So, I looked for a solution online and came across one that suggested to `cd` into `/var/lib/dpkg` and run `rm *`. I did it and then I was able to get past the `apt-get update`.

Now when I try to install something using `apt-get install`, it gets to here and hangs

```
Setting up linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic (3.19.0-43.49~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-43-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-43-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-43-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.19.0-43-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.19.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.19.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-43-generic
```

and it just sits here, not sure what it's doing. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

This is what I did.

> This should be used as last resort. If you use this carelessly you can
>   end up with a broken system. Please try the other answers before doing
>   this. You can delete the lock file with the following command:
>
> sudo `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` You may also need to delete the lock
>   file in the cache directory
>
> sudo `rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` After that, try opening Synaptic
>   again.

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted the contents of that folder. The only possible solution seems to be a fresh installation.

Comment: I hope not @Raphael , I have stuff set up on this server I would hate to redo... makes ya wonder why I didn't take a snapshot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [pathname.com](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE31):

> `/var` contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.

Note where it says **spool directories and files, administrative and logging data**, this part is important. By deleting `/var/lib/dpkg` you deleted some very important files.

Apart from above:

> `/var` is specified here in order to make it possible to mount `/usr` read-only. Everything that once went into `/usr` that is written to during system operation (as opposed to installation and software maintenance) must be in `/var`.

It means: the data in `/var` changes, which is necessary, for some applications such as in your case `dpkg`.

You should **never** delete files/folders without prior knowledge. The only left possible solution is for you to reinstall Ubuntu. Until you do so, you'll be unable to use `dpkg`. But the **best part** here is that you still have a **running** system, so, backup all your important data, i.e., the ones present in `/home`, etc. so, that you don't lose anything during a re-installation.

Comment: Doesnt the ubuntu iso have some sort of "fix" for this, where it repairs a system? Wish I could find that site that said to run the delete command...

Comment: It wasn't the entire folder just the lock folder off of apt, could it be a read write issue.... I may have had a issue with a folder in var/ that I chmod 777 +R

Comment: Could you post a link to the tutorial you are following?